# Compiler considers only first EPL statement

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

Currently I am trying to combine several EPL statements with Esper CEP 8 in Java. When I read single EPLs in EPCompile, they all work as if they were turned on. For example:

```
String EPL1 ="@name('EPA12') select * from IEvent where j>3;\n";
```

But when I try to read multiple EPL-Operations at once, only the first one is considered. For example, if I try the following statement, it only checks for j>3 and CEP prints all events for it. But i>4 (EPA13) is not checked.

```
String EPLnotworking ="@name('EPA12') insert into EPA12 select * from IEvent where j>3;\n"+
"@name('EPA13') select * from EPA12 where i> 4;";
```

The compilation by Java works without any problems. Is it possible that I have modeled my problem incorrectly?

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.getCommon().addEventType(IEvent.class);

String EPLnotworking ="@name('EPA12') insert into EPA12 select * from IEvent where j>3;\n"+
    "@name('EPA13') select * from EPA12 where i> 4;";

EPCompiled compiled = EPCompilerProvider.getCompiler().compile(EPLnotworking, new     CompilerArguments(configuration));

runtime = EPRuntimeProvider.getDefaultRuntime(configuration);
DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new     DeploymentOptions().setDeploymentId("IEvent");

EPStatement stmt = runtime.getDeploymentService().deploy(compiled, deploymentOptions).getStatements()[0];

stmt.addListener(new UpdateListener() {
public void update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents, EPStatement statement, EPRuntime runtime) {
    if (newEvents == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (EventBean event : newEvents) {

        System.out.println(event.get("i"));
        System.out.println(event.get("j"));

    }
  }
});

public void run() {
//recieve Events
IEvent test = new IEvent();
// test.setI(received);
runtime.getEventService().sendEventBean(test, "IEvent");
}
```

I notice that the CEP generates an output even with values of i=<4.

Does anyone know where the problem is?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not stating what is "not working". Does "not working" mean there are no output events? Perhaps that is because the code attaches a listener only to the first statement and ignores the second statement. You could attach a listener to all statements.

```
EPStatement[] stmts = runtime.getDeploymentService().deploy(compiled, deploymentOptions).getStatements();

for (EPStatement stmt : stmts) {
  stmt.addListener(new UpdateListener() {
    public void update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents, EPStatement statement, EPRuntime runtime) {
    if (newEvents == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (EventBean event : newEvents) {

        System.out.println(event.get("i"));

    }
  }
  });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I gave two EPL statements in my example. The EPLnotworking - doesn't work as it should. With this EPL only the @name(EPA12) is considered but not the @name(EPA13). The statement generates an output like in EPA12 but does not filter like in EPA13. My goal was not to combine EPLnotworking and EPLworking. Rather, EPLworking should show that an EPL statement works with only EPA12 - as in EPLworking - but an extension of EPA13 does not work.

Comment: You need to attach a listener to see output

Comment: You mean add EPLnotworking to complied? Yes, I am aware of that. The real problem is that EPLnotworking doesn't work even if I add it to the compiled EPCompiled object like EPLworking does. I've already tried this with several statements. Always only the first part (EPA12) is considered in EPworking but not the EPA13 part. Maybe my question is a bit unclear, I will change my question.

Comment: "deploy" returns an EPDeployment object and that has a reference to ALL statements. Attach a listener to each statement and not just the first. I.e. "deployment.getStatements()" and a use a loop over all statements.